# error while loading shared libraries failed to map segment from shared object

Tags: clamav

```
Y9@Y9Acer:~$ clamd
clamd: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object
```

Why is this error happening? And how can I fix this.

```
Y9@Y9Acer:~$ ldd $(which clamd)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeb03e0000)
    libclamav.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclamav.so.7 (0x00007f45d8f80000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f45d8cfc000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f45d8add000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f45d86ec000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f45d832b000)
    libmspack.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmspack.so.0 (0x00007f45d8118000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f45d7f08000)
    libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f45d7cfe000)
    libLLVM-3.9.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.9.so.1 (0x00007f45d5116000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f45d4d8d000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f45d4b23000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f45d46ab000)
    libz.so.1 => /home/yannik/local/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f45d448e000)
    libjson-c.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.3 (0x00007f45d4283000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f45d4011000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f45d3c73000)
    libtfm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtfm.so.1 (0x00007f45d3a39000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f45d3821000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f45d958e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f45d3619000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f45d33f3000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f45d31d7000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f45d2ebc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f45d2cb8000)
    libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007f45d2901000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f45d26f9000)
    libedit.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2 (0x00007f45d24c2000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f45d2298000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f45d2083000)
    libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007f45d04da000)
```

Comment: Check your virtual memory limit (ulimit -a)